# How to pass bearer token in $window.open url

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am opening the url without authentication using below code,

```
   $window.open(downloadUrl);
```

I want to use below authorization

```
   Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '123hrwertjwtjwjrtr',
```

i have used below code but it is not working,

```
    var params = 
 {
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '123hrwertjwtjwjrtr',
   'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 };
var downloadUrl = somedummyurl;
var url = [downloadUrl, $.param(params)].join('?');
$window.open(url);
```

Can anyone suggest how to add bearer token while calling the api url.
In api am using httpget method and used authorize tag..

Comment: It's not possible to have call `$window.open()` with custom HTTP headers. What's the reason you need to use the latter? `$http.get()` in AngularJS can be configured with header arguments.